# Кафка и метки по ней

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Увидел следующие метки: [kafka](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kafka)  - по ней 51 вопрос и к ней есть описание в вики, вторая - [apache-kafka](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-kafka) - описание в вики нет, но уже 66 вопросов.

Мне кажется, что стоит оставить одну из этих двух меток, так как вопросы, касаются одной и той же темы. Предлагаю оставить ту, что уже имеет описание.

Comment: А почему не ту, по которой больше вопросов?

Comment: @Qwertiy, можно и так сделать. Тоже вариант, а описание забрать у метки kafka.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз уж пошла дискуссия в комментариях, то отвечу. Я выбрал (и рекомендую другим использовать) наиболее описательную метку в качестве основной, когда одного имени метки уже может быть достаточно для понимания о чём речь, без необходимости обращаться к описанию, как краткому, так и подробному.

Модераторы могут легко скопировать описание из одной метки в другую, так что наличие описания не должно влиять как-либо на исход выбора какую метку использовать в качестве основной. Сложности появляются, если обе метки имеют описание и эти описания различны. Нужно делать какую-то компиляцию из двух текстов, поэтому в таких случаях рекомендуется также предлагать итоговое описание метки в предложении о синонимизации.

Comment: Понимаю вашу мысль. Уже вижу, что произошла миграция под метку apache-kafka. Согласен с таким подходом. Она более описательная.

Comment: Можно прямо пояснить, что метка вида [компания-библиотека] лучше, чем просто [библиотека], а то вдруг ещё какая-нибудь кафка появится :)

Comment: @Зонтик часто бывает наоборот: одна и та же библиотека/программный продукт переходит из рук в руки, как Java (изначально Sun Microsystems, сейчас Oracle) или С++ Builder (изначально Borland, теперь Embarcadero, между ними еще CodeGear был). С фондом Apache Software Foundation вряд ли что-то случится, но в любом случае вряд ли кто-то создаст еще одну кафку.

Comment: @Зонтик, т.е. продукт часто живет дольше чем компании-разработчики, я бы оставлял метки без названий компаний.

Comment: @insolor Если библиотека/технология/продукт сменят владельца (или даже название) модераторам не сложно "переименовать" метку под новые реалии.